# Connecting UITextField in Interface Builder to IBOutlet defined in code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder

Any idea why IB doesn't let me make this connection?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Identity Inspector for that views File's Owner, make sure that the Class is set to `MainScreenViewController`. If you could add a screenshot of your MainScreenViewController.xib window that may be more helpful.

Comment: That right view is what opens if I double click on MainScreenViewController.xib

Comment: Which .xib opens the left view controller?

Comment: Hmm, I can't replicate the issue. Did you check to see if `MainScreenViewController` is set as the Class in the Identity Inspector for the right views File's Owner?

Comment: I got it! Instead of opening MainWindow.xib and looking at its controller connections, I needed to open MainScreenViewController, click on File's Owner and THEN look at the controller connections. From there I could see textField that I could then link with.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to link two different IB documents, i.e two different .xib files, which is not possible. I think you really only want to have one .xib file here.